# Range-based for loop on a temporary range

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary-objects, c++20, for-range

Thanks to some segmentation faults and warnings in valgrind, I found that this code is incorrect and has some sort of dangling reference in the for-range loop.

```
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>

auto f(){
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v(10, std::vector<double>(3));
    iota(v[5].begin(), v[5].end(), 0);
    return v;
}

int main(){
    for(auto e : f()[5])
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It looks as if the `begin` and `end` is taken from a temporary and lost in the loop.

Of course, a way around is to do

```
    auto r = f()[5];
    for(auto e : r)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
```

However, **I wonder exactly why `for(auto e : f()[5])` is an error and also if there is a better way around or some way to design `f` or the even the container (`std::vector`) to avoid this pitfall.**

With iterator loops is more obvious why this problem happens (`begin` and `end` come from different temporary objects)

```
for(auto it = f()[5].begin(); it != f()[5].end(); ++it)
```

But in a for-range loop, as in the first example, it seems very easy to make this mistake.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code: what are you trying to achieve with it? Because if it's only purpose is jagged array initialization, there are better methods.

Comment: Yes, and there's a proposal for C++20 to partly address this issue: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0614r1.html

Comment: @JHBonarius, what is "jagged array initialization"?

Comment: Initialization of an array of arrays...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that using a temporary as the range expression directly is fine, its lefetime will be extended. But for `f()[5]`, what `f()` returns is the temporary and it's constructed within the expression, and it'll be destroyed after the whole expression where it's constructed.

From C++20, you can use init-statement for [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to solve such problems.

(emphasis mine)

> If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended
>   until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue
>   reference __range, but **beware that the lifetime of any temporary
>   within range_expression is not extended**.
>
> This problem may be worked around using init-statement:
>
> ```
> for (auto& x : foo().items()) { /* .. */ } // undefined behavior if foo() returns by value
> for (T thing = foo(); auto& x : thing.items()) { /* ... */ } // OK
> ```

e.g.

```
for(auto thing = f(); auto e : thing[5])
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
```

Comment: Cool. Can initial statements be used in normal for loops as well?

Comment: well yes, but not to predefine auxiliary variable of arbitrary type.

Comment: @alfC I got what you mean; it seems impossible for normal for loop.

Comment: For example, it could accept (with modifications to the language), something similar to lambda captures, e.g. `for[thing = foo()](auto it = thing.begin();}; it != thing.end(); ++it)`.

Comment: @alfC Yes; and you might want to make a proposal for it. :)

Comment: @alfC for(*init*; *check*; *inc*) allows *init* to be a single [simple declaration ](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations), of whatever type you like. It need not relate to *check* or *inc*

Comment: @Caleth, yes, but you cannot initialize two variables with different types in `init`. For example the counter/iterator (`thing.begin()`) and some auxiliary variable (`thing = f()`).

Comment: Why is `for (auto& x : foo().items()) { /* .. */ }` undefined behavior. If `items()` is returning something by value, say it is a function returning a `std::vector<int> items(){....}`, then wouldn't that vector have its lifetime extended per the lifetime extension rule? Even though `foo()` may be temporary it seems that in this case it is fine as long as `items()` is returned by value. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @cogle You're right. The point here is that `itmes()` returns by-reference; the returned reference from the temporary returned by `foo()` becomes dangled after the temporary gets destroyed. Just like in OP's question, `operator[]` returns by-rereference too. If `items()` returns by-value, as you said it'll be fine.

Answer (score 15):

> I wonder exactly why `for(auto e : f()[5])` is an error

I'll just answer this part. The reason is that range-based for statements are just syntactic sugar for, approximately:

```
{
    auto&& __range = f()[5]; // (*)
    auto __begin = __range.begin(); // not exactly, but close enough
    auto __end = __range.end();     // in C++17, these types can be different
    for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto e = *__begin;
        // rest of body
    }
}
```

Take a look at that first line. What happens? `operator[]` on a `vector` returns a reference into that object, so `__range` is bound to that internal reference. But then the temporary goes out of scope at the end of the line, destroying all of its internals, and `__range` is immediately a dangling reference. There is no lifetime extension here, we are never binding a reference to a temporary.

In the more normal case, `for(auto e : f())`, we'd bind `__range` to `f()` directly, which *is* binding a reference to a temporary, so that temporary would get its lifetime extended to the lifetime of the reference, which would be the full `for` statement.

To add more wrinkles, there are other cases where indirect binding like this would still do lifetime extension. Like, say:

```
struct X {
    std::vector<int> v;
};
X foo();

for (auto e : foo().v) {
    // ok!
}
```

But rather than try to keep track of all of these little cases, it's much better to, as songyuanyao suggests, use the new for statement with initializer... all the time:

```
for (auto&& range = f(); auto e : range[5]) {
    // rest of body
}
```

Although in a way this gives a false sense of security, since if you did it twice, you'd still have the same issue...

```
for (auto&& range = f().g(); auto e : range[5]) {
    // still dangling reference
}
```

Comment: Would the syntactic sugar be "better" (for this problem) if it had `auto const& __range = f()[5]; // (*)`?

Comment: @alfC Nope. Same outcome, just you get a const lvalue reference instead of a non-const rvalue reference. You definitely want `auto&&` there, otherwise you'd only get `const` access.

Comment: ok, I was thinking that `... const&` would extend the lifetime. As for const access, that depends on the semantics of `.begin()` in principle. In practice you are right.

Comment: I question "it's much better to [use the new initializer feature]".  The very clutter-free loop (which is, I think, the entire point of range-based-for loops) has suddenly become rather cluttered, and we've lost a lot of what range-based-for previously gained, in my opinion.  As for "range-based-for is just syntactic sugar for... "; understood, and I am hoping it will be changed in the future to being syntactic sugar for <a different snippet of code with less surprising lifetime semantics>.